# flutter disable certain days of the week when showing date picker based on a list

Tags: flutter, datepicker, disable

I have a list showing days of the week. 1 is for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, 3 for Wednesday etc.

```
List<int>? daysOfWeek = [1,2,3];
```

When I use the showDatePicker how do I use selectableDayPredicate: to disable those days of the week.

```
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                    firstDate: DateTime(2021),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2023),
                    selectableDayPredicate: ????
                  ),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime dateTime) => !daysOfWeek.contains(dateTime.weekday)`

Comment: it seems that if 'today' is not included in the list of daysOfWeek, it will give an exception. Do you know any workaround for this problem?

Comment: @jayne you need to always disable or enable "today"? or you need always to disable the list except "today"?

Comment: for example, my DaysOfWeek = [1,3,5]...that's MWF...and today is Thursday which is 4, it's giving me an error of 

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker.dart': Failed assertion: line 175 pos 5: 'selectableDayPredicate == null || selectableDayPredicate(initialDate)': Provided initialDate 2022-07-28 00:00:00.000 must satisfy provided selectableDayPredicate.

my initialDate: DateTime.now(),

Comment: @jayne so in this mentioned case, what do you like the initial date to be? it is according to your business rule. maybe you need today is always selectable, maybe you need to make the initial date at tomorrow if today exists in the list... etc.